# Let $\gamma$ be the unit circle {$e^{i\theta}$ : $-\pi \leq \theta$ $\leq-\pi$}. Find $\int_{\gamma}e^zz^ndz$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\gamma$ be the unit circle {$e^{i\theta}$ : $-\pi \leq  \theta$  $\leq-\pi$}.  Find   $\int_{\gamma}e^zz^ndz$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence evaluate the corresponding real integrals.

How would I apply the CIF here without a $w$ in the interior of $\gamma$.

Comment: You can take $w=0.$

Comment: The result will simply be zero since the integrand is holomorphic.

Comment: @Apocalypse $n\in\mathbb Z$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen If $n$ is negative we can apply the Cauchy Integral Formula for derivatives.

Comment: @Apocalypse We can, but OP seems to be having trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\ge 0$, the function $f(z)=e^z z^n$ is analytical throughout the complex plane, therefore its integral over any closed path is zero. For $n<0$ the only non analytical point inside the unit circle is $z=0$ therefore $$\int_{\gamma}e^zz^ndz=2\pi iRez_{z=0}(f)$$where$$Rez_{z=0}(f)={1\over (-n-1)!}\lim_{z\to 0}{d^{-n-1}\over dz^{-n-1}}z^{-n}f(z)={1\over (-n-1)!}$$therefore$$\int_{\gamma}e^zz^ndz={2\pi i\over (-n-1)!}$$